# what dependencies to add for HTTP in gradle file android; ByteArrayBody, HttpMultipartMode, StringBody does not resolve

Tags: java, android, http

I have added the following in gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.entity.mime.content'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.swuljcityconductor"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Also I have added the following to Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I want to send image files over HTTP POst.
Anything else should I do?
The keywords
ByteArrayBody, HttpMultipartMode, StringBody does not resolve.
What else should I add?

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit is best one for http in android, have some  caching and more features, u can read in https://square.github.io/retrofit/ and https://github.com/square/retrofit